# 502 bad gateway nginx and apache servers

Tags: nginx, apache-2.4, 502-error, 502

Hello there can you please help me im trying to setup apache and nginx server on my ubuntu 16.04 server, but when i try to visit localhost/info.php fo example im getting

> 502 Bad Gateway nginx/1.9.15 (Ubuntu)

error 502 bad gateway and this is from the error log file:

> 2017/01/24 10:50:55 [error] 14774#14774: *29 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client:
>   127.0.0.1, server: example.com, request: "GET /info.php HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:8080/info.php", host: "localhost"

my  /etc/apache2/ports.conf is:

```
Listen 8000

<IfModule ssl_module>
    Listen 443
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_gnutls.c>
    Listen 443
</IfModule>
```

my /etc/nginx/sites-available/default file is:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

    root /var/www/html;

    # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
    index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name 127.0.0.1;

    location / {
        # First attempt to serve request as file, then
        # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;
            include /etc/nginx/proxy_params;
    }

    location ~* \.(js|css|jpg|jpeg|gif|png|svg|ico|pdf|html|htm)$ {
        expires      30d;
        }

    }

       location @proxy {
                proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;
                include /etc/nginx/proxy_params;
       }
       location ~* \.php$ {
                proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;
                include /etc/nginx/proxy_params;
       }
}
```

my /etc/nginx/nginx.conf file:

```
user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections 768;
    # multi_accept on;
}

http {

    ##
    # Basic Settings
    ##

    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    keepalive_timeout 65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;
    # server_tokens off;

    # server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
    # server_name_in_redirect off;

    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    ##
    # SSL Settings
    ##

    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    ##
    # Logging Settings
    ##

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    ##
    # Gzip Settings
    ##

    gzip on;
    gzip_disable "msie6";

    # gzip_vary on;
    # gzip_proxied any;
    # gzip_comp_level 6;
    # gzip_buffers 16 8k;
    # gzip_http_version 1.1;
    # gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

    ##
    # Virtual Host Configs
    ##

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}
```

rights and ownerships of /var/www/html folder:

```
➜  html sudo ls -lah /var/www/html          
общо 40K
drwx--s--x  6 dimitar www-data 4,0K яну 24 10:44 .
drwxr-sr-x  3 dimitar www-data 4,0K дек 28 12:26 ..
-rw-r-Sr--  1 dimitar www-data  12K яну 24 00:52 index.html
-rw-r--r--  1 dimitar www-data   18 яну 24 10:44 info.php
drwxrwsr-x  6 dimitar www-data 4,0K яну 10 14:02 Laracast
drwxrwsr-x  2 dimitar www-data 4,0K яну 23 20:17 phpmyadmin
drwxrwxrwx  5 dimitar www-data 4,0K дек 16 11:28 softuni
drwxrwsr-x 12 dimitar www-data 4,0K яну  3 20:04 users
```

the output of sudo netstat -lntp:

```
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:7845            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      5054/skype      
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:30666         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      31454/Viber     
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3306          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2521/mysqld     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:139             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2523/smbd       
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      14328/nginx -g daem
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:4371          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      28075/spotify   
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:5940          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2301/teamviewerd
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:57621           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      28075/spotify   
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:45112         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      31454/Viber     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:220             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1233/sshd       
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:4381          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      28075/spotify   
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:445             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2523/smbd       
tcp6       0      0 :::139                  :::*                    LISTEN      2523/smbd       
tcp6       0      0 :::220                  :::*                    LISTEN      1233/sshd       
tcp6       0      0 :::445                  :::*                    LISTEN      2523/smbd       
tcp6       0      0 :::8000                 :::*                    LISTEN      15002/apache2
```

the content of /etc/nginx/proxy_params:

```
proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

client_max_body_size 100M;
client_body_buffer_size 1m;
proxy_intercept_errors on;
proxy_buffering on;
proxy_buffer_size 128k;
proxy_buffers 256 16k;
proxy_busy_buffers_size 256k;
proxy_temp_file_write_size 256k;
proxy_max_temp_file_size 0;
proxy_read_timeout 300;
```

can someone please give me a hand and help me?

Comment: Hi, please show us  the permissions/ownership of `/var/www/html` - `sudo ls -lah /var/www/html`

Comment: @13nilux, added!

Comment: and output of `sudo netstat -lntp` please

Comment: What is the contents of `/etc/nginx/proxy_params`? Does it override the `proxy_pass` directive?

Comment: @13nilux added the info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After two days I've finally managed to solve my problem. Thanks to this [page](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-nginx-as-a-web-server-and-reverse-proxy-for-apache-on-one-ubuntu-16-04-server)

I've ended up deleting the `/etc/nginx/sites-available/default` file and I have only one apache file.

Just following the instruction in the page where it says enter your ip address you can enter `127.0.0.1` if you are only trying to set it up for your local env.

Also you can skip 8 part and follow other parts as you don't need them. Those are for setting up so your server/com can be visible outside of our network so to call - Internet :)